# Fixing Google play warning for cordova project: Existing Cordova project does not upgraded to latest version

Tags: android, cordova, security

Yesterday i got a mail from google play team they notice that You are using a vulnerable version of Apache Cordova please upgrade to version 4.1.1 or higher to fix the vulnerability.

Now my project cordova version is `4.0.2` and  i am updating it using the command

```
cordova platform update android
```

Here is the result form it

```
cordova platform update android
Updating android project...
Android project updated with cordova-android@4.0.0
```

But when i check my project cordova version  ist still `4.0.2 ,it dosen't updated to newer version.

My cordova version is `5.0.0`

Comment: You have to update cordova CLI first, latest version is 6.0.0, not 5.0.0, then you'll get cordova android 5.1.0 when you do the cordova platform update

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, which will install the latest version of Cordova Android:

> cordova platform update android@5.1.0